# OpenCV3.10 core.hpp must be compiled in C++

Tags: c++, opencv3.1

i have installed OpenCV 3.10 and the linked the `opencv_world310.lib` to `release` and `opencv_world310d.lib` to debug.
Moreover I put the compiler options in search directory to `...opencv\build\include`. I got a undefined reference error when i left out `#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp`. Now that i have included it my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>


int main(void){

printf("HALLO!");


return 0;
}
```

When i try to build it core.hpp opens and the `error: core.hpp must be compiled in C++` occurs.
I am using the GNU GCC Compiler in Codeblocks.
What should i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you compiler options. Open CV 3.10 C++ API requires code to be compiled as C++, but not C. You can use answer to ["CodeBlocks: change project language c and c++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695896/codeblocks-gcc-change-project-language-c-and-c) question to change the options.

Also use the new Open CV 3.10 API

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`
```

instead of all the other Open CV header files. This header includes core functionality. To enable *highgui* module you need to define `HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI` in your project settings.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer it does solve my problem!